# Understanding PyDict_Check behaviour

Tags: python, cpython

I've been playing around with the Python C API for a while. I like it a lot but today I hit a roadblock. I have a Python extension that has a function which expects one or two dictionaries as argument. I fear I might have misunderstood how `PyDict_Check`, or `PyArg_ParseTuple` works. Here's a dumbed down example:

```
static PyObject * doStuffToOtherStuff(MyCustomPyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
  char const *fmt = "OO";
  PyObject dict1, dict2;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, fmt, &dict1, &dict2))
    return NULL;

  int hasDict1 = PyDict_Check(&dict1);
  int hasDict2 = PyDict_Check(&dict2);

  printf("%d %d\n");

  Py_INCREF(Py_None);
  return Py_None;
}
```

When built and imported I call it like this for example:

```
myClass.doStuffToOtherStuff(dict(), None)
```

I expect this to print  `1 0`  but it actually prints  `1 1` . So does:
    myClass.doStuffToOtherStuff(None, None)
    myClass.doStuffToOtherStuff(None, dict())
    myClass.doStuffToOtherStuff({}, None)
    #etc...

If I change `PyDict_Check` to `PyDict_CheckExact` it prints `0 0` instead, no matter what I pass as arguments.

Any insight will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyArg_ParseTuple` with `O` arguments expects a pointer to a `PyObject *`, not a pointer to a `PyObject` (i.e. the variadic argument should be of type `PyObject **`).

So your code should be:

```
  char const *fmt = "OO";
  PyObject *dict1, *dict2;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, fmt, &dict1, &dict2))
    return NULL;

  int hasDict1 = PyDict_Check(dict1);
  int hasDict2 = PyDict_Check(dict2);

  // ...
```

Comment: Have a python code example for return the two objects?